# Convert from byte array to string and Split String

Tags: c#, split

Let's say I have a byte array

```
Byte[] arr;
```

Then I will convert the array to string 1st.

```
String inputString = "";
foreach (Byte b in arr)
{
   if (b != 0)
      inputString += (Char) b;
   else inputString += " ";
}
```

Let's say the string is:

```
inputString  = @"C:\Program Files\Test C:\Users\User A\AppData\Local\Temp C 32323 C:\Program Files\Test\Temp";
```

I want it to be split into 4 strings that look like below:

```
C:\Program Files\Test \\position 0 = test folder
C:\Users\User A\AppData\Local\Temp \\position 1 = windows temp folder
C 32323 \\position 2 = a name. It can be C2313 or C 2312 or whatever string
C:\Program Files\Test\Temp \\position 3 = temp for test folder
\\ position can change by me...
```

every string in between will be split by space. That's mean I can use .Split(' '). However, as you know some of the path has space in between, 'C:\Program Files\Test' is an example.

How can I get the values I want?

Comment: Are you sure the original `byte[]` didn't have a `\0` between the various paths? Try changing `inputString += " "` to `inputString += "|"`

Comment: substrings `C:\Users\User A\AppData\Local\Temp` and `C 32323`? following the pattern, it should be `C:\Users\User A\AppData\Local\Temp C 32323` folder, isn't it?

Comment: @xanatos it will surely have more than one \0

Comment: I'd suggest that code converting a `byte` array to `string` that doesn't make use of an [`Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is broken code

Comment: @ASh no, it is C:\Users\User A\AppData\Local\Temp and C 32323

Comment: Is it the `0` from the byte array that marks the split?

Comment: so you want to split based on a space that is followed by the char `c`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled There are many possible byte array. Not necessary only the example. I think my implementations are incorrect. That's why need help from expert here.

Comment: @kingjia I'm just wondering about that `c 323232` row, just like Ash. I want to make sure I understand what is your criterion for the split.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have updated the 4 strings example. Please take a look....

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make it any clearer. If any string can be considered as valid, how can you decide if `Files\Test` is a part of `C:\Program Files\Test` or if it's a standalone string (and so is `C:\Program`)?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
byte[] arr = ...

string[] inputStrings = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(arr).Split('\0');
```

And see the result.

Comment: the array inputStrings  contains a lot of empty strings.

Comment: Try posting the result array... I can't debug with this informations.

Comment: @kingjia You could post the base64 version of the `byte[] arr`: `string arrToString = Convert.ToBase64String(arr)`

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for your advise to use inputString += "|".

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. Thanks @xanatos for the advise.

```
String inputString = "";
bool isRepeat = false;
foreach (Byte b in arr)
{
   if (b != 0)
   {
      inputString += (Char)b;
      isRepeat = false;
   }
   else
   {
      if (!isRepeat)
      {
         inputString += "|";
         isRepeat = true;
      }
   }               
}
```